# use blurry-image-load with several images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I have an issue with this plugin [blurry-image-load](https://github.com/tushariscoolster/blurry-image-load), because it only allows me to display an image due to absolute positioning with styles, for example if I want to put two pictures one beside the other using a model 12 columns of bootstrap It happens that an image is positioned above the other.

How I can control the positioning?

I made a script with this refered example
https://plnkr.co/edit/931AzFwG5DI52p34A3Nz?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="col-md-6">        
    <div class="placeholder" data-large="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=1010">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/20/15?image=1010" class="img-small">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="placeholder" data-large="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/freeze/max/27/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg?q=20" class="img-small">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 66.6%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.placeholder {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.placeholder img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.placeholder img.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-small {
  filter: blur(50px);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {

  var placeholder = document.querySelector('.placeholder'),
      small = placeholder.querySelector('.img-small')

  // 1: load small image and show it
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = small.src;
  img.onload = function () {
   small.classList.add('loaded');
  };

  // 2: load large image
  var imgLarge = new Image();
  imgLarge.src = placeholder.dataset.large; 
  imgLarge.onload = function () {
    imgLarge.classList.add('loaded');
  };
  placeholder.appendChild(imgLarge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all...
I don't think you put enough effort in it in trying to get things to work.

Secondly...
Your JavaScript only 'processes' the **first** placeholder by using `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` which is all documented at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp).

Lastly...
If you're making use of bootstrap, use the elements as documented at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

`.col-*-*` are children of `.row` which in turn is a child of `.container` or `.container-fluid`

FYI...

css styles shouldn't be included in the html file anymore, make use of classes instead.

Below the code which works for me:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var placeholders = document.querySelectorAll('.placeholder'),
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < placeholders.length; i++) {
    blurryLoad(placeholders[i]);
  }
}

function blurryLoad(element) {
  var small = element.querySelector('.img-small');

  // 1: load small image and show it
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = small.src;
  img.onload = function() {
    small.classList.add('loaded');
  };

  // 2: load large image
  var imgLarge = new Image();
  imgLarge.src = element.dataset.large;
  imgLarge.onload = function() {
    imgLarge.classList.add('loaded');
  };
  element.appendChild(imgLarge);
}
```

```css
.placeholder {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.placeholder img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.placeholder img.loaded {
  /*This is a overqualified selector. For the html as is now .loaded is enough*/
  opacity: 1;
}
.img-small {
  filter: blur(50px);
}
.padding {
  padding-bottom: 66.6%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Cols -->
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="placeholder" data-large="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=1010">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/20/15?image=1010" class="img-small">
        <div class="padding"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="placeholder" data-large="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg">
        <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/freeze/max/27/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg?q=20" class="img-small loaded">
        <div class="padding"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @alejokum Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of the Bootstrap is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
    <div class="col-*-*"></div>
</div>
```

See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) or [Bootstrap itself](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) for a detailed overview of Bootstrap Grid System.

You're missing the `<div class="row">` inside your HTML.

Comment: Better yet... See getbootstrap.com for complete and latest documentation.